# how to delete amature data in blender?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have 3 armatures in my character, how can I remove the armature 002 001?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. delete it in the "normal" outline by selecting it and then press x

[image]

then change to orphan data:

[image]

[image]

select it and right click -> delete

[image]